# Why does d3.select() return array of array?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I recently started using `d3.js` to write some scripts to manipulate SVGs. So most of the time I refer d3 documentation and find the solution. However I cannot understand why `d3.select` function return array of arrays. For example let's say i have an `SVG` element and if I do `d3.select("svg")`, it returns `[[svg]]` so I have to do `d3.select("svg")[0]`. The documentation says

> One nuance is that selections are grouped: rather than a one-dimensional array, each
>   selection is an array of arrays of elements. This preserves the
>   hierarchical structure of subselections

Then says we can ignore it most of the time.

1. Why does it return array of array ?
2. What does

> This preserves the hierarchical structure of subselections

mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to know or care how the object `d3.select` returns is structured internally.  All you need to know is which methods are accessible in that object, which is what the documentation describes.

Say you have this document:

```
<div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

If you select all `<div>` elements with `d3.selectAll`

```
var div = d3.selectAll("div");
```

the `div` is a d3 selection object of size 2, one for each `<div>` element in the document.

But if you now generate a subselection from this selection object

```
var span = div.selectAll("span");
```

a search is made for matching elements within each element in the `div` selection, and the structure is preserved -- i.e., the `span` selection will contain the same number of elements as the `div` selection it was based on, and each of these will consist of a selection of elements found in that element.

So in this case, `span` will contain two selections (first `<div>` and second `<div>`), each of which will contain two elements(1 and 2 in the first, 3 and 4 in the second).

As for `select`, it is the same as `selectAll` except it stops after finding one match; its return is structured exactly the same way, however.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myfNP/)

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Thanks. "You shouldn't need to know or care how the object d3.select returns is structured internally" I am curious and that's the whole idea which i wanted to ask this question.